# Xamarin forms FreshMVVM: short link to specific detailpage as a toolbar item

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

Using FreshMvvM for a Xamarin forms based MasterDetailPage, I am seeking for a way to place a short link to a specific detail page as a ToolbarItem on top of the each Detail page.

How can I navigate to a specific Detail page once tapping on this short link?
The following command navigates to the desired target detail page but blows away the entire navigation!?

```
private async void OnShortLinkButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.Current.MainPage = FreshMvvm.FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<MyDetailPageModel>();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The whole point of using a master detail page is to have the links to other detail pages on the master (popout) page, not as links at the top of each detail page.

Comment: The whole point of websites, such as stackoverflow, is to help people solving problems that deviate from standard issues ;)

Answer (score 0):

The link you show in your example sets App.Current.MainPage to the new Detail page. That, as you say, will blow away the whole navigation stack.

What you want to do is set the Detail property of the current MasterDetail page to the new detail page.

One way to do this is to send a message using the Messaging Center - you could create a new ChangePage message and pass an enumeration of the detail pages as the parameter.

In your MasterDetail page subscribe to the ChangePage message and have a switch statement that replaces the current detail page with the new one.